# font-weight on vector icons breaks elements alignment

Tags: html, css

I have a `div` containing a vector icon (in this example, a fontawesome icon).

The icon is horizontally aligned to the right and I expect it to be on the edge of its container (the `div`). Everything works as expected as you can see here (you'll probably have to zoom a lot)

https://jsfiddle.net/k0h56myn/

where the icon and the bottom border start at the same *x* coordinate (the red line is to show the perfect pixel alignment):

[image: wow]

Adding `font-weight: 700;` style to the icon breaks this alignment, see below:

[image: :(]

I assume that `font-weight` does only "expand" the icon by *n* pixels, not caring at all of the object repositioning and alignment.. am I right?

Do you have any trick to prevent this in order to have a perfect and ocd-approved alignment?

Comment: Font icons are typically not designed to be used with font-weights other than the default (normal, i.e. `400`), unless otherwise specified. So, when you declare a font weight other than that, the browser might attempt to render it as a pseudo-bold font, which messes up alignment. Don't use font-weight declarations on font icons.

Comment: thanks for the suggestion, it makes total sense.

Answer (score 0):

There is no position (Alignement) changed here. It was act like a normal fonts. While adding font weight, the font become somewhat bold. All the text fonts also will look like this only. This is not an issue.